# Making a contact form shrink

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make this contact form shrink as the screen size shrinks down but I'm not sure how to approach the task as I've used flexbox to position the email and phone input fields. Any flexbox that I apply to the form class messes with the layout of the form.

The form that I'm trying to replicate can be viewed at the botton of the page. As you shrink your screen you can see the layout of the form stays the same, the size of each input field just shrinks.

P.S Ignore the redundant style code that I've repeated. Just cleaning it all up now.

```css
.form {
width: 828px;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex: 0 0 calc(500% - 20px);
}
.home-name {
background: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
width: 828px;
height: 38px;
padding: 14px auto;
}

.home-phone {
background: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 406px;
height: 38px;
margin: 16px auto;
margin-right: 16px;
}

.home-email {
background: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 406px;
height: 38px;
margin: 16px auto;
}

.home-message {
background: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 828px;
height: 167px;
}

.form-button {
margin: 20px auto;
max-width: 828px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.home-message-contact {
margin-top: 20px;
}

input {
text-indent: 10px;
}

textarea {
text-indent: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
 <div class="form">

                        <div class="name-form">
                          <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="home-name" required>
                        </div>
                      
                        <div class="phone-form">
                          <input type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="home-phone" required>
                        </div>
                      
                        <div class="email-form">
                          <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="home-email" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="message-form">
                          <textarea  type="text" placeholder="Message" class="home-message" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-button">
                            <button class="home-message-contact" type="submit">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                        
                      
                      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using a lot of pixel value, you can start changing them to percentage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified an absolute pixel value of 828px. This won't change with or without flexbox.

You should change the absolute value to something relative such as 90vw or 90% based on how much of the screen you want it to take up.

Once you've done this you'll need to set the form to:

```
> flex-direction: column;
```

Which will help you with the previous issue of the layout being messed up.

I've included a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/msmfa/pen/vYNvzjO) with these changes and a few other minor tweaks to give you a general idea of what I would personally do for sake of ease.

Comment: When I change flex-drection to column it then screws up the email and phone input. I want them to stay on the same row.

Comment: Then wrap the phone and email input in a div and apply a flexbox to it. Here is a codepen of what I mean https://codepen.io/msmfa/pen/vYNvzjO

Comment: Thanks! I keep on forgetting to create sperate divs

Comment: When I place your code within a section that has the following css then it doesn't stay aligned centered as the screen shrinks - .container6-heading {
 margin: 60px auto;
 max-width: 1170px;
 text-align: center;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 30px);
}

Comment: Here's a link to my question regarding the problem. If you could help that would be amazing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61940377/why-doesnt-this-form-stick-to-justify-content-center-set-by-its-parent-conta/61940795?noredirect=1#comment109554528_61940795

Comment: What is it that you're trying to accomplish? It might be easier to know that then try and retrospectively fix something

Comment: I've fixed it with margin left right auto. As the screen shrinks it wasn't staying center of its container

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your flexbox to have a max-width of 828px and the contact form able to shrink.

```css
.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.home-name {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  max-width: 828px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 14px auto;
}

.phone-email-form {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 828px;
}

.phone-form {
  flex-basis: 406px;
  margin: 16px auto;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.home-phone {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 38px;
}

.email-form {
  flex-basis: 406px;
  margin: 16px auto;
}

.home-email {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 38px;
}

.home-message {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 828px;
  height: 167px;
}

.form-button {
  max-width: 828px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.home-message-contact {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

input {
  text-indent: 10px;
}

textarea {
  text-indent: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="form">

    <div class="name-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="home-name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="phone-email-form">
      <div class="phone-form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="home-phone" required>
      </div>

      <div class="email-form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="home-email" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="message-form">
      <textarea type="text" placeholder="Message" class="home-message" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-button">
      <button class="home-message-contact" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>


  </div>

</body>

</html>
```